# Will Ubuntu 12.10 or 12.04 Run Very Smoothly on My Computer Or Should I Go With Lubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, lubuntu, performance

I have a somewhat old computer with mid-range hardware.
Here's what my computer has:

1.8 Ghz Willamette Pentium 4 256 Kb L2 Cache
nVidia Geforce 6200 LE 256 mB DDR2
1024 mB DDR at 133 mhz
40 GB HD 5400 RPM

Before, I used Fedora 17 with my computer, and installation was somewhat long, about 25% (All night installation) longer than Windows XP (Which took 2 hours). It ran at an OK speed, but it was slow and constantly lagged in all areas. This included starting LibreOffice in Fedora 17, loading the Applications screen, scrolling down the Applications screen, and even when switching a wallpaper and it took more than 15 seconds just for Mozilla Firefox to start up, so I eventually switched back to Windows XP in frustration with disappointment at the speed of Fedora 17.

However, I've gotten tired of XP and I want to go back to Linux. I'm looking at the Ubuntu 12.10 & 12.04 requirements which demand 512 mB of RAM and a 1.0 Ghz Pentium 4 processor, but I'm not sure if I should install Ubuntu, or try going with another desktop environment such as Lubuntu, which I've been looking into. With my previous experience with Fedora 17, I'm not sure whether or not my computer will run very smoothly using Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10. As a result, I'm kind of stuck between Lubuntu and Ubuntu...

Comment: I run Ubuntu 12.04 with desktop effects on a good old Sony tx3xp: - Celeron 1,2 Ghz, - 1 Gb ram - 80 Gb 1,8" 5400 rpm - Integrated Intel express graphic card
It's running fast and fine with desktop effects enabled (I mean standard Ubuntu session, not Unity 2D). Smoothly could be the good word ;-) However, I tried 12.10 and it was very slow on this laptop.

Comment: Please create a Ubuntu USB disk (see here how, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) and boot your computer from it. You will get some rough idea how your computer will behave with these Ubuntu versions. My general impression is, I have _not seen_ any computer doing _specially bad_ with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest going directly to Lubuntu (but try the Lubuntu live USB before) because of your hardware specs. I currently use Lubuntu 12.10 on an older computer and it runs very smooth.

Comment: the livecd installation requires 400-800 mb of memory.  which the OP doesnt have.  he need the alternate cd.  if you use the livecd to install on low-ram pcs, you get paused installs (which the op mentioned)

Comment: @marinara The OP says that he has 1024MB ram, that's more than enough for the liveCD to be installed. I have done it successfully in lower specs machines.

Answer (score 0):

I use my Windows 10 x64 PC which is:
Ubuntu 12.04 on Virtualbox
Dual core processors(Intel Celeron 2.16 GHz
RAM @ 2GB 1.88 usable
500GB Hard Disk

So when I run Ubuntu, It boots up quickly then It showing Login Screen at 15 sec.
Very smooth and runs perfectly.
When I open Mozilla Firefox browser, It takes 20 sec. to launch the browser. Just like my Firefox browser in Windows launched at 58 sec.
Meaning, the firefox browser on Windows, than the linux Mozilla Firefox browser is much great to use.
My secret is to getting fast the system is the Swap. I Partitioned the swap within 10 GB which the system uses a lot within 610 MB or 899 MB.

Optional. For Windows users using Ubuntu on Virtualbox.:
Here is the Setting up to make your Ubuntu works properly.

PCs with:
Adjust on Virtual box Motherboard RAM:

1GB                                 <512MB (320 or maybe 448.)

2GB                                 512MB. If it any something interruptions, raise at <600MB or 544MB

3-4GB                               <800MB or 1GB completely.(1024MB)
8GB and above                        2GB

The more RAM on your PC, the more merrier fast using.
-Jay